# Off-line, half bridge. Weird primary voltage

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, dc-dc-converter, switching-regulator

I'm working with this circuit:

[image: Output stage]

I only show the power section, which is not working well.
It is a SMPS working in open loop, so that I can manually adjust the PWM signal. The capacitor C10 is not mounted on the board.

The parameters of the circuit are:

- VDD = 15 V
- VD = 311 V
- Vo = 24 V @ 2,5 A (approx 50 W output power)
- Switching frequency = 80 kHz

For the test, I connected a load of 25 ohms and gradually increased the PWM level.

The following figure shows the voltage on the transformer primary on the TP6, taking the TP7 as a reference point. I think the signal has an acceptable shape. Corresponds to an output of approximately 3 V

[image: Primary voltage, Vo = 3 V]

I set the control signal so that the output voltage (Vo) is 7 V, and I get the following signal as voltage in the primary:

[image: Primary voltage, Vo = 7V]

In addition to the "hump" that appears in the zone of zero voltage, the asymmetry in the amplitude of the pulses is notorious.

Taking the output voltage to 17 V, an oscillation is observed:

[image: Primary voltage, Vo = 17 V]

And this is the waveform for 24 V at the output:

[image]

**My question is**: why this behavior? What would be a possible solution?

At first I thought that it could be a magnetizing current (transformer) too high, but increasing the output current level (by varying the connected load) does not change the effect.

I apologize for the quality of the images, I hope they can serve as reference for the description of the problem.

**EDIT**: Here is the input rectifier block with reference to point `PRI_MID`

[image]

Comment: Obviously, there is an asymmetry in either the drive or the load. That low-frequency ringing effect needs to be investigated. My first question is, what is `PRI_MID` connected to? If it isn't solidly bypassed to the primary ground, odd things could certainly happen. Try looking at all four terminals of the transformer (single-ended, not differential).

Comment: @DaveTweed PRI_MID is connected to the mid point of filter capacitors in the input rectifier.

Comment: What kind of capacitors are they? What ESR/ESL do they have at 80 kHz and above?

Comment: @DaveTweed , I dont know exactly. I'll look for the manufacturer's data. What should I pay special attention to?

Comment: What do you see with the scope on `PRI_MID`? Why did you think it would be a good idea to connect C8 there rather than directly to ground?

Comment: @DaveTweed on PRI_MID the signal is 155 Vdc with 3 Vpp 100 Hz ripple. The C8 connection corresponds to the half-bridge topology.

Comment: The point is, if you're already blocking DC with C8, why do you need a DC midpoint connection? Usually, it's either one or the other. You really need to study where your high-frequency loop currents are flowing.

Comment: What waveforms do you get from TP6 to GND and TP7 to GND?

Comment: @DaveTweed that configuration is often seen in PC power supplies.

Comment: Does the ringing go away when you load the output with higher current?

Comment: @JohnD No. The oscillation stays the same, even increases the amplitude somewhat. The tests were conducted with current between 10% and 50% of the maximum current.

Comment: @BruceAbbott from TP7 the signal is 155 Vdc with 3 Vpp 100 Hz ripple. From TP6 the signal maintains the shape that is observed in the photograph, only that is 155 V displaced from zero.

Comment: If Tp7 is constant 155V then the transformer primary has up to ~50V across it when both transistors are off, suggesting asymmetrical drive or loading. What do the waveforms look like at Tp9 and 10, are they symmetrical?